# SQL query for monthly bills with amounts paid

Tags: sql, mysql, finance

The idea is to get a listing of monthly bills with amounts paid. The subquery does a total through a group by using `bill_id` and `party_id`.

I wish to know how it can be improved. I'm not comfortable with `JOIN`s and am willing to learn.

```
SELECT
    bill.id as bill_id,
    master.id as party_id,
    master.name as party_name,
    `amountExcVat`,
    bill.vat,
    amountExcVat + bill.vat as 'amtIncVat',
    `purchasedDate`,
    (SELECT SUM( cashPaid ) + SUM( chequePaid ) 
     FROM  `partypayment`
     WHERE party_id = partyId AND bill_id = partyBillId
     GROUP BY partyId, partyBillId)
    as 'Amount Paid(cash+chq)',
    bill.status
FROM `partybill` as bill, `partymaster` as master, partypayment as payment
WHERE
    bill.partyId = master.id
    AND
    bill.partyId = payment.id
    AND
    UPPER(MONTHNAME(`purchasedDate`)) = 'OCTOBER'
    AND
    YEAR(`purchasedDate`) = '2013'
```

Tables are as follows. **They provided by a third party so I can't modify them.**

> ```
> create table partymaster (
> id INT(4)
> ,name varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY
> ,address varchar(200)
> ,contactNo1 BIGINT(14)
> ,contactNo2 BIGINT(14)
> );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> create table partypurchase (
> id  INT(10)
> ,partyId INT(4) references partymaster(id)
> ,head varchar(100)
> ,brand varchar(100)
> ,size varchar(10)
> ,costPrice INT(6)
> ,sellingPrice INT(6)
> ,quantity INT(4)
> ,totalCost INT(10)
> ,purchasedDate date
> );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> create table partybill (
> id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY
> ,partyId INT(4) references partymaster(id)
> ,amountExcVat INT(10)
> ,vat INT(10)
> ,amountIncVat INT(10)
> ,purchasedDate date
> ,expectedPaymentDate date
> ,status varchar(10)
> );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> create table partypayment (
> id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY
> ,partyId INT(4) references partymaster(id)
> ,partyBillId INT(10) references partybill(id)
> ,cashPaid INT(10)
> ,chequePaid INT(10)
> ,chequeBankName varchar(50)
> ,chequeNumber INT(10)
> ,chequeDate date
> ,paymentDate date
> );
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the subquery?

```
SELECT
bill.id as bill_id,
master.id as party_id,
master.name as party_name,
`amountExcVat`,
bill.vat,
amountExcVat + bill.vat as 'amtIncVat',
`purchasedDate`,
bill.status,
SUM(payment.cashPaid) + SUM(payment.chequePaid) as 'Amount Paid(cash+chq)',
FROM `partybill` as bill, `partymaster` as master, partypayment as payment
WHERE
party_id = partyId AND
bill_id = partyBillId AND
bill.partyId = master.id AND
bill.partyId = payment.id AND
UPPER(MONTHNAME(`purchasedDate`)) = 'OCTOBER' AND
YEAR(`purchasedDate`) = '2013'
GROUP BY partyId, partyBillId)
```

(I just wrote this without testing it so it might not work right out of the box)

Since you are already querying *partypayment* you should be able to do this